# Distribution of Y influenced by predictor X in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model

One of the assumptions in simple linear regression is that the error term is supposed to be normally distributed. Now, I found on the internet the following quote:

"You’ll notice there is nothing similar about Y.  ε’s distribution is influenced by Y’s, which is why Y has to be continuous, unbounded, and measured on an interval or ratio scale.

But Y’s distribution is also influenced by the X’s.  ε’s isn’t.  That’s why you can get a normal distribution for ε, but lopsided, chunky, or just plain weird-looking Y."

My question is: is this true? I actually thought it was the other way around, that the distribution of Y is NOT influenced by the predictors.

Comment: In linear regression, specifically OLS, the full set of assumptions termed the "classical linear model" assumptions states that $Y$ is normally distributed conditional on $X$. X can follow any distribution you can think of, the conditional distribution of Y is entirely determined by that of the error term.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the quote so that we can see some context.  Do you know what conditional probability means?

Comment: This is the full quote:

Comment: For some reason I am not allowed to post the entire quote, due to too many characters involved. The full quote is found here: http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/assumptions-about-residuals/ which is a short article about the above question. I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The quote the OP links to starts with a mistake by referring to the "residuals" while all these assumptions refer to the *errors* (the residuals are the *estimated* errors).

Apart from that when we specify a regression equation, we state that as a variable, $Y$ is a function of $X$'s and the error term. It is then natural to say that the distribution of $Y$ will be influenced by the distribution of $X$'s and of the error term, since they *determine* $Y$ itself.

As a simple example, assume that $Y =  a + bX + u$, where $u$ follows a  Normal but $X$ follows say, a Gamma distribution, then the distribution of $Y$ cannot be normal, and what it will be will depend on the distribution of $X$ also, and how it "mingles" with the distribution of $u$. Etc.

Even if the regressors are "deterministic", meaning that they cannot be said to follow a statistical distribution, they still affect the parameters of the distribution of $Y$: in the previous example with deterministic regressors, the distribution of $Y$ will be normal with modified mean (but same variance).

In the "conditional expectation function" approach, in principle we consider the joint distribution of $\{Y,X\}$ and the resulting conditional one, and the distribution of the conditional expectation function error springs from these (i.e. here the error is not treated as a separate variable but is defined as $u\equiv Y- E(Y\mid X)$ )

So in all cases, the distribution of $Y$ is influenced by $X$, in one way or the other.

Comment: My issue here is that the x values are chosen so it is not meaningful to assume  a Gamma distribution for X.  I think that assuming measurement error in X puts the problem in the realm of error in variables regression sometimes called Deming regression.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple linear regression model, $E(Y)$ is a linear function of $x$ -- $E(Y|X=x) = \beta_0+\beta_1 x$.

The mean of the conditional distribution of $Y$ depends on the value of $X$, indeed that's kind of the point of a regression model. So the distribution of $Y$ depends on $X$.

Comment: I am bothered by this interpretation.  The basic assumption in linear regression and the justification for OLS is that X is given without error and all the error in Y is due to the noise term.  The variability observed in X is due to the sample design. So for the Model Y does not depend on X . Now looking at the residuals after the fit along with the observed values of Y may look diferent

Comment: I'm mystified by this comment. If (say) we assume normality of errors, so that we have $Y\sim N(\beta_0+\beta_1 x,\sigma^2)$, you're claiming that the distribution of $Y$ doesn't depend on $x$, even though it appears explicitly in the density function?

Comment: That is not what I am saying.  The view is that you only at the value of Y given x.  Of course the regression function depends on x.  But that does not mean that we assign a probability distribution to the x values.  We assume that they are determined by design and each individual measurement is observed with no error (idealist yes, but legitimate if  actual errors in x are relatively small).  This is a common view to justify OLS.  Look up "Ordinary Least Squares" on wikipedia, especially the section on the modeling assumptions. @Glen_b.

Comment: @Michael, At no point did I say we assign a distribution to the X-values. In regression it doesn't matter whether X is a random variable or not (since we condition on it). But the issue at hand is the OP's misunderstanding in the line "*the distribution of Y is NOT influenced by the predictors*" -- the conditional distribution of Y **is** explicitly influenced by the predictors because the conditional mean depends on them. And the marginal distribution of $Y$ is similarly affected, since if you change the arrangement of the predictor-set you change the distribution of the $Y$'s.

Comment: Your answer  is fine.  You should notice that my comments were placed under the other two answers which I have a disagreement with.  The only thing that you said that I disagreed with was "you're claiming that the distribution of Y doesn't depend on x even though it appears explicitly in the density function?"

Comment: I believe I'm referring here only to comments you have made under my answer.